# Configure Windows Azure Caching (preview) Cache Client Programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-caching

Trying to convert from Windows Azure Shared Caching to Windows Azure Caching (Preview) where I was able to programmatically configure the DataCacheFactory via the DataCacheFactoryConfiguration class.  Is the possible in the Caching (Preview)?  If so, what are the values that need to be set for the server configuration?

Take a look at the old documentation ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg618003.aspx ) I have not been able to find the "preview" version of this documentation.

Comment: I too am looking for this. It appears not to be possible. In experimenting I get errors if I leave autoDiscover enabled and try and set the Server property of the factory config, but then if I remove autoDiscover it fails as well. I just want to specific a specific tcp port to use.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be possible, yet.

Answer (score 0):

The "How to" documentation on using Windows Azure Caching Preview is [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/). To include nuget package for Caching Preview please check section "Getting Started with Windows Azure Caching (Preview)" and also take a look at the section "Working with Caches" which shows code on how to use API.

As these two cache are fundamentally different because on is locally available and another one is in cloud, the libraries and API to configure Cache and Cache objects are different in between two. The key difference is that Caching Preview uses the following different reference:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;
```

and the code which is depend on above is different as documented above in provided links i.e.

```
DataCacheFactory cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory();
DataCache cache = cacheFactory.GetDefaultCache();
```

Comment: That is all good content, but that code still depends on having set the correct values in the .config file.  The OP is trying to do this without the .config file.

Comment: @knightpfhor that is correct, I am still looking to do this without the config file settings.